# Generating random functions (not numbers!) - How to implement

Tags: algorithm, function, data-structures, pseudocode

I need to generate random functions. For example, if I have a function set `F={sin, cos}` and a variable set `V={x, y}`, I should be able to produce functions like following:

- `f_1(x,y)=sin(x)`
- `f_2(x,y)=cos(y)`
- `f_3(x,y)=sin(x) + cos(y)`
- `f_4(x,y)=sin(x**2)-3xcos(xy)`

What would I need to use (Data structure, algorithm etc.)? 
I'm open to your ideas and advice.

Comment: Too open-ended a question. Anyway, you should look into symbolic computation packages, which should allow you to compose atoms into arbitrarily complex expressions. Another idea that comes to mind is [straight-line programs (SLPs)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/76248/intuition-behind-straight-line-programs).

Comment: I would probably use the grammar for expressions in <your favorite programming language> and use that as a generator. But yeah, this question is really too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider your set of functions, possible variable name (e.g. 'x', 'y') and operators +, -, *, **, (,) etc. as an alphabet. Construct a grammar for the valid expressions. Construct a corresponding state machine that produces sentences of your expression language on transition sequences from start node to end node. Implement the state machine to follow a random branch at each node. Voila ...

Ask further questions in comments to this answer  if necessary